# python print done after while

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new to python:
my aim is to print a done statement after while loop
but it gives me syntax error

```
>>> i=0
>>> while i < 10:
...  print i
...  i=i+1
...
... print "done"
  File "<stdin>", line 6
    print "done"
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
<?php

$i=0;
while($i<10)
{
echo "$i \n";
}
echo "done";
?>
```

I am trying to replicate the same php program in python

i tried

```
>>> i=0
>>> while i < 10:
...  print i
...  i=i+1
... print "done"
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    print "done"
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

still it fails
cant we use a print after end or do we have to wait for the while to finish and do the print

Comment: Sounds like Python 3.x complaining that print should be called as a function, e.g. `print("done")`

Comment: Then why would `print i` work?

Comment: I thought that was the problem too but i tested the code in 2.6 and received the same error. I think it is because you are trying to execute multiple statements at the same time within the shell. I tested this with an if statement and got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see '>>>', you **are not writing a program**. You are using an interpreter. You feed it one statement at a time.

If you want to write a program, save it in a plain text file with a .py extension. You should be able to run this by double-clicking it (although it will not pause at the end, so you might just see the command window flash), or by supplying the file's name as an argument to `python` at the command line.

Answer (score 4):

First-level blocks in the REPL must be terminated by a *completely* empty line.

```
>>> i=0
>>> while i < 10:
...   print i
...   i=i+1
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>>> print "done"
done
```

Comment: i tried >>> i=0
>>> while i < 10:
...  print i
...  i=i+1
... print "done"
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    print "done"
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 3):

Just get rid of that space on your empty line after the while loop. The space makes the interpreter think that the loop is continuing.

Comment: Yep. Most likely a case of extra space on the line between i=i+1 and print "done"

Comment: It looks like you got rid of the blank line. Keep the blank line, just make sure it has no spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [`while..else` control structure](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement). The code would then be:

```
>>> i = 1
>>> while i < 10:
...     i = i + 1
... else:
...     print 'done'
...
...
done
>>>
```

Though this would typically be written in python as:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     pass
... else:
...     print 'done'
...
...
done
>>>
```