# bug in python interactive mode?

Tags: python, interactive

i got the syntax error reaction while try coding like bellow in python interactive mode.

```
>>> while True:
...   reply = raw_input('enter text:')
...   if reply == 'stop':
...     break
...   print reply
... print 'bye'
  File "<stdin>", line 6
    print reply
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

but it executed normally if save as script.

```
~ $cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding=utf8

while True:
  reply = raw_input('enter text:')
  if reply == 'stop':
    break
  print reply
print 'bye'
~ $python test.py
enter text:19
19
enter text:456789
456789
enter text:$%^&*(
$%^&*(
enter text:TGHJKLO:P
TGHJKLO:P
enter text:#$%^&*()_
#$%^&*()_
enter text:stop
bye
```

is it a bug? or any other things i should know about python interactive mode?

```
~ $python -V
Python 2.6.6
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python print done after while](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751135/python-print-done-after-while)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python print done after while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751135/python-print-done-after-while)

Answer (score 2):

I think when you return to the first column of indentation this must be left empty its to indicate that the block you opened is now ready to be interpreted.

If you put this in a function an invoke it after it works properly.

```
    In [66]: def fun():
   ....:     while True:
   ....:         reply = raw_input("enter text:")
   ....:         if reply == 'stop':
   ....:             break
   ....:         print reply
   ....:     print "bye"
   ....:
```

Comment: Is that mean every blocks return to the first column is now ready to be interpreted in interactive mode? Got it. Thanks.