# Why am I getting an invalid syntax error in Python REPL right after IF statement?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I think this is perfectly valid.

```
if False:
    print(1)
print(2)
```

However, it gives me an invalid syntax error in Python REPL.

Why is it?

[image]

On Python 3.6.5 (x64), Windows 10 RS4

Comment: This is weird. Works in ipython but not in python shell

Comment: Umang Gupta is right, it is really weird, but if you want to avoid it, you can do an else statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python print done after while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751135/python-print-done-after-while)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by user2357112, this behaviour is explained in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming,

> The body of the loop is indented: indentation is Python’s way of grouping statements. At the interactive prompt, you have to type a tab or space(s) for each indented line. In practice you will prepare more complicated input for Python with a text editor; all decent text editors have an auto-indent facility. **When a compound statement is entered interactively, it must be followed by a blank line to indicate completion (since the parser cannot guess when you have typed the last line). Note that each line within a basic block must be indented by the same amount.**

Comment: I thought it just means you need to enter a blank line to end and evaluate the multi-line construct. It seems not only that...

Comment: That's not really a great docs quote for this, because "continuation lines" in that documentation doesn't just refer to the blank line. (The previous paragraph says "for continuation lines it prompts with the secondary prompt, by default three dots (`...`)", and the `the_world_is_flat` example is showing what kinds of lines the `...` prompt is used for.)

Comment: There's a more relevant statement [later in the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming): "When a compound statement is entered interactively, it must be followed by a blank line to indicate completion (since the parser cannot guess when you have typed the last line)."

Comment: @user2357112 True. Re-reading it, after your comment, made me realise it.

Answer (score 0):

The REPL can only read and evaluate one statement at a time.
You entered two statements at once.

This is possible because the REPL cannot decide if the third line is going to continue the `if` construction or start a whole new statement. It has to assume the former to allow indented blocks at all.

You have to make it clear to the REPL that your previous statement is finished before starting a new one.

Answer (score -2):

Wrong version seems to be the most possible since, in the error it shows print. In the older python versions, print was used as print"ok", I see your operating system is windows so you can just directly download python3 from ***https://python.org/*** have a nice day!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31721109)