# Why am I getting a syntax error if the same syntax works outside of the (for lack of proper term) list of commands?

Tags: python

This is my code, I’m learning on free code camp and this is the code that works perfectly on his screen but not one mine, any idea what’s wrong with the syntax? For context, if I put the syntax error line in after Python tells me I have a syntax error, it prints.

```
››> count = 0
>>> print('before', count) 
before 0
>>> for thing in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] :
     count =count + 1 
     print (count, thing)
    

print ('After', count)
File "«stdin>" line 4 print('After',count)
AAAAA
SyntaxError: Invalid syntax
```

I haven’t tried doing anything yet, it’s just not adding up in my head why none of this is working.

Comment: This only happens in the REPL; you need to leave a blank line at the end of an indented block.

Comment: This is a quirk of the interactive shell.  You need to enter a blank line to tell the shell that the loop is finished.

Comment: Hi! I did what both of you said but it’s still not working, any idea why?

Comment: I don't see a `>>>` before the unindented content in your transcript. There should be `...`s when the REPL thinks you're in a block and then `>>>` when it knows the block is done; you should write code outside the block only when you're back to `>>>`

Comment: Same problem as [Why am I getting an invalid syntax error in Python repl right after `if` statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50901923/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-syntax-error-in-python-repl-right-after-if-statement), or [Python print done after while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751135/python-print-done-after-while)

Comment: Note that when you talk about an instructor's screen ("works on his screen"), it matters which shell each of you are using -- if one of you is using IPython vs regular `python`, or IDLE, or so forth, that can make a difference in interactive behavior. For the most consistent/reliable behavior it's safer to just write your code in a file and run the file; the dev/test cycle becomes longer, but takes this class of problem completely off the table.